# how to change default button from .Xdefaults?

Tags: configuration, c

I am trying to hide/desensitize the default button in an application that although I have source for, I cannot/may not compile.

Here is (part of) the code:

```
_messageBox = XtVaCreateManagedWidget("_messageBox",
        xmMessageBoxWidgetClass,
        _form,
        XmNmarginHeight, 0,
                    XmNnavigationType, XmNONE,
        XmNtraversalOn, False,
                    XmNtopAttachment, XmATTACH_WIDGET,
                    XmNtopWidget, separatorBottom, 
                    XmNrightAttachment, XmATTACH_FORM,
        NULL);

XtVaSetValues(XmMessageBoxGetChild(_messageBox, XmDIALOG_OK_BUTTON),
              XmNhighlightThickness, 0,
              NULL);
```

I would like to be able to something like the following in my .Xdefaults file:

```
tgui*_messageBox*DIALOG_OK_BUTTON*foreground: red
```

I don't know how to reference the button in the .Xdefaults file.

Any suggestions?